# Negating sentences - " If I had not ..., I would ..."

Tags: american-english, auxiliary-verbs, negation

I want to make negative sentences from positive sentences.  For example:

> If I **had** a car ..., I would ... 　　 ←　*positive*
>
> If I **had not** a car, I would ...　　←　*negative*

But I'm not sure about it would be correct edited as well?

---

Also what is the difference between these two negative sentences?

> If I **had not** a car, I would ...
>
> If I **did not have** a car, I would ...

And is there any other option to another expression?

Edit: I do not just tell about question and positive, negative structure grammar.

Comment: **If I hadn't a car** is common. But note this is with *had* and *not* contracted. *If I had not a car* sounds as strange as *If I have not a car.*

Comment: The usual and most common construction is _if I didn't have a car_. In negative sentences (and questions!) you normally add the auxiliary verb _do_: I have a car -> I don't have a car -> Do you have a car?

Comment: Regarding your edit: You are asking a _question_, I presume. If you want to _tell_ us something about something, a blog is a better place. Instead of **SHOUTING** at us what you are **not** talking about, it would help if you would simply clarify your _question_ and tell us what you _are_ talking about.

Comment: I don't have idea which point makes you as miss understood.

Comment: ***\*If I hadn't a car*** isn't actually common.  The negative inflectional affix ***-n't*** attaches to auxiliary verbs, but possessive ***have*** for the large majority of speakers is now lexical, and for these speakers ***\*If I hadn't a car*** is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If I did not have a car, I would...* is correct here.  *If I had not a car* is not, because you aren't negating the right element.  "a" is the indefinite article, but it also counts 'one' in a sense.  As such, you would need to negate 'a':

> If I had a car, I would drive to the store.

becomes

> If I had no car, I would walk to the store.

However, in English you would more commonly say "did not have a car", because negating "have" makes more sense, and so "did not have" places the emphasis on that part of the sentence.  You could also say "If I did have a car," which would emphasize that also, but we don't tend to in my experience.  I'm not entirely sure why the distinction, but "If I had no car" sounds odd to me despite being technically sound, and "If I did have a car" also sounds a little off.